# Trying to print out step by step in a recursive function without printing them out all at once in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, recursion, dom, timeout

I'm trying to make an N-Queens visualizer and I hooked up my solver to the html doc. My issue is that I'm trying to display everything step by step with intervals of 1 second each for the **place** function, rather than showing the completed solutions right away.

In other words, I want to show each move done step by step.

My placing function, is also hooked up to the tables on the DOM so when it's being placed on the board, it also places it on the html table.

```
function place(board, row, col, val, table) {
  const newRow = board[row].split('');
  newRow[col] = val;
  board[row] = newRow.join('');
  //place on DOM as well
  table.childNodes[row].childNodes[col].innerHTML = val;
}
```

and the code I have for my solver is this

```
function solver(board, row, col, solutions) {
  if (col === board.length) {
    solutions.push([...board]);
    return;
  }

  const currentTable = listOfTables[solutions.length];

  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    if (canPlace(board, i, col)) {
      place(board, i, col, 'Q', currentTable);
      solver(board, row, col + 1, solutions);
      place(board, i, col, '.', currentTable);
    }
  }
}
```

I was trying to wrap a setTimeout inside the solver function but that still runs the code all at once, when the timeout hits.

The currentTable variable is the used to know which of the tables in the DOM is currently going to be in use.

Here's the CodePen with all the code if anyone needs it https://codepen.io/vvus/pen/KKVKMrq?editors=1111

Comment: One way could be push all the moves into an array and then at the end loop over that with timeout.

Answer (score 0):

you can adjust the code bellow to your liking

you add the `display="none"` to all your tables and then you deactivate the attribute in a time interval using this code

```
var i=0

setInterval(() => {
          for(z=i;z<listOfTables.length;z++)  {      
    const x=document.getElementsByClassName('new-table')[z]
          if (x.style.display === "none") {
              x.style.display = "";
                       i++                                
          }    
               break  
                       }
            }, 3000);
```

so your final code may look like this

```
const button = document.getElementById("button-click");
    const selection = document.getElementById("selection");
    let tablesContainer = document.getElementById("tables-container");
    let listOfTables = tablesContainer.childNodes;

    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(nQueens(Number(selection.value)));

      listOfTables = tablesContainer.childNodes;
     // add this code to your eventlistner or anywhre you want to show something in time interval
      var i=0
       setInterval(() => {

          for(z=i;z<listOfTables.length;z++)  {      
    const x=document.getElementsByClassName('new-table')[z]

          console.log(z)
          if (x.style.display === "none") {
              x.style.display = "";
                       i++                                
          }    
               break  
                       }
            }, 3000);

    });

    selection.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
      let numOfTables = e.target.value;

      if (numOfTables === 1) numOfTables = 1;
      else if (numOfTables === 4) numOfTables = 3;
      else if (numOfTables === 8) numOfTables = 93;

      const rowsCols = e.target.value;
      for (let allTables = 1; allTables < numOfTables; allTables++) {
        const newTable = document.createElement("table");
        newTable.classList = "new-table";
        newTable.style.display="none"// add this attribute to all your tables
        for (let i = 0; i < rowsCols; i++) {
          const row = document.createElement("tr");

          for (let j = 0; j < rowsCols; j++) {
            const th = document.createElement("th");
            th.innerHTML = ".";
            row.appendChild(th);
          }
          newTable.appendChild(row);
        }
        tablesContainer.appendChild(newTable);
      }
    });
```

Comment: This is somewhat closer to what I want to achieve, but what I actually need is to display every single attempt for the place function. So something similar to the solution you gave me, but focused on the place function.